# Can deployed RIDE scripts on Waves Platform be deleted, modified or overwritten?

Tags: wavesplatform, ride

If we find a bug on a deployed RIDE script or if we want to make enhancements, is it still possible to modify the script or replace with a new script?

Answer (score 1):

It will depend if your first stript allows this.
For example a scripted asset can prevent a setscript tx for this asset and then you are stuck with the current script.